# Windows 11: the bottom of snapped windows on second monitor are placed behind taskbar

Tags: multiple-monitors, taskbar, windows-11

I've recently moved to windows 11 on two separate systems. In both cases I'm working on a laptop (1920x1080 display) and have a 3840x1600 second monitor connected. I've enabled "show taskbar on all displays" and disabled "automatically hide the taskbar"

Firstly: when I make a window full screen on the second display, the whole taskbar disappears. I already consider that a bug, but I don't have issue with that as I rarely work with that.

When I snap a window on the second display to either side, it uses the whole display **-excluding the taskbar-** as reference, thus the bottom part of the window is placed ***behind*** the taskbar. This is especially annoying for things like chat apps in browsers, where the input field is hidden behind the taskbar.

Windows 10 did not have this problem. I've been looking online, but haven't found any solutions. The only work-arounds are either making the second monitor my main display (which I don't want), or disabling the taskbar on the second monitor (which I don't want).

(Note: so this only happens on the second monitor. The first/primary monitor handles the taskbar correctly.)

Does anybody have a fix, or should I just accept that win 11 is broken?

Comment: I just experienced the same issue on a new Windows 11 install. Moving the windows from screen 2 to screen 1 and back seemed to fix the issue, but no idea really what happened there ...

Comment: I've had this problem for "a while", maybe even since Windows 10 but I'm not sure. Earlier it could temporarily be solved by activating "hide the taskbar" and deactivating it again, but that doesn't seem to work any longer.
Also, Maximilian's solution isn't working for me either.

Comment: It only seems to happen on ultrawides as second screen.